# how to track clicks on outbound links on AMP container

Tags: google-analytics, next.js, google-tag-manager, amp-html

I'm trying to create a tag that tracks clicks to external links from some of my pages. In the past I have never had problems in creating them on web container but now I have to create them for amp container and I am having many problems. Is it possible to get help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use data-vars to get variable in GTAG-Manager via AMP like:
<a data-vars-youvarname="linkurl" href="linkurl>
and in GTAG-manager you can use the custom var {yourvarname}